# Принцип записи данных на LTO_6 файловой системой LTFS

Tags: linux

Кто сталкивался со стандартом записи на магнитную ленту LTO-6 файловой системой LTFS, позволяющей осуществлять доступ к файлам, хранящимся на магнитной ленте, по аналогии с файлами на дисках?    Если, как показывает тестирование, на перемотку ленты затрачивается ее свободное пространство. Что же произойдет, если записать ленту полностью до предела? Достать данные будет невозможно, в связи с нехваткой места для перемотки ленты до нужного блока и выход из этой ситуации только заново форматировать ленту и потерять всю информацию?? Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться!

Comment: может быть, вы спутали с тем фактом, что пространство, занимаемое удалёнными файлами, не может быть использовано повторно (до пересоздания файловой системы)?

Comment: действительно, все так как вы говорите.. т.е. фактически  удаление нельзя произвести на ленте и повторно использовать этот объем (не делая дефрагментацию или новую файловую систему)?